# Target multiple IP addresses in SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack

I know it's possible to target a specific IP address or a CIDR using salt's `-S <ip_addr>` option but let's say I only want to target specific IP addresses and not the entire CIDR, how do you do this in salt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [compound targeting](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/targeting/index.html#compound-targeting):

```sh
salt -C 'S@192.168.0.5 or S@192.168.1.2' test.ping
```

If you're frequently targeting the same set of minions, you could also define a [nodegroup](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/targeting/nodegroups.html) for them.